# Dojo 1.10 ON event from select dropdown does not work

Tags: dojo

I have the following select dropdown:

```
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" id="legendPane" data-doprops="title:'Monuments', selected:true" >
        <select id="selSection" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select">
          <option value="0">Section</option>
          <option value="1">Gulf of Maine</option>   
          <option value="2">Passamaquoddy Bay</option>
          <option value="3">St. Croix River</option>
          <option value="4">North Line</option>
          <option value="5">St. John River</option>
          <option value="6">St. Francis River</option>
          <option value="25">The 49th Parallel, Columbia Valley to Pacific</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

And I have the following on-event:

```
    var selSec = registry.byId("selSection");
    on(selSec, "Change", function(evt) {
     alert("test");
    });
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything. Where Am I going wrong?
Thanks,
Gido

Comment: In addition to @MiBrock answer, Are you parsing the widgets before calling the registry.byId function call? Can you show the entire code?

Comment: It says the code is too long, though it's only 112 lines.

Comment: ready(function(){
  parser.parse();
});

Comment: How can I share the entire code?

Comment: where and how are you calling the code that you have mentioned in the second snippet i.e `var selSec = registry.byId.......` can you edit this section.

Comment: to share your code need to use pastebin.com or jsfiddle.com

Comment: I put it in the require block.  The on-event capture works with a button, but not with the select.  May-be something is wrong with my select widget?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these former SO-Post. It handles exactly the same Prob you are facing.

[How do I programmatically change a select so that it fires its onchange behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224728/how-do-i-programmatically-change-a-select-so-that-it-fires-its-onchange-behavior)

By the way: Have you checked if your selSec finds the right widget?

Regards, Miriam

Comment: The on-event fires, within the JS, but not within the Dojo part.  I just don't understand how one captures the on-event in the Dojo part.

Comment: @Gido Can you try to use the following. `selSec.on('change', function(evt) {
        alert('test'); console.log("onchange called");
    });`

Comment: That didn't complete loading the script; I got a "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" error.

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SbZ9y/), though it's recommended not to be using the `dojo/on` to capture widget based events (like the `onChange` from the `dijit/form/Select`).

The more recommended approach of capturing that event is by using the `dijit/form/Select::on()` function, for example:

```
registry.byId("selSection").on("change", function() {
    // Do something
});
```

Back to your issue, make sure that you're waiting until the widgets on the page are parsed by using the `dojo/ready` module.

Also make sure that you have configured dojo to parse widgets when the DOM is ready by setting `parseOnLoad: true`. Finally, make sure your `require()` function is correct by checking the following:

- The modules loaded are in the same order as the variables inside the `require()` callback
- You're loading `dijit/layout/ContentPane` and `dijit/form/Select` (they're necessary as well, even when you use declarative markup)
- You're loading the `dojo/parser` module, which is necessary to parse widgets on the DOM.

Comment: Here comes the master dojo(Dimitri) ;-)

Comment: I tried the registry approach; but that didn't even complete the loading.  I think I did all the rest you pointed out; even though I am very new to Dojo stuff.  The on-event works actually very well with an image array that I am using.

Comment: If it didn't complete the loading, then I think you're not waiting for the page to complete parsing the widgets. Are you sure you're wrapping your calls inside the `ready()` function? Also check your browser console for errors.

Comment: I also tried the `dijit/registry::on()` approach on the fiddle, same result, it works fine there: http://jsfiddle.net/SbZ9y/1/ So I'm pretty sure the error is somewhere else (not waiting long enough, not loading the correct modules, ...). However, without the code necessary to reproduce the problem, we cannot help you further and we can only guess what the problem is.